# Changes in "processing" in QGIS 2.18.10?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I've been running following code:

```
processing.runalg("grass:v.voronoi", self.input_file_path + file_name + ".shp", False, True,
                      extent, -1, 0, 3, file_name_poly)
```

or an example in plain text:

```
processing.runalg("grass:v.voronoi", 'C://Users/Matrix//Downloads//MsaviData//AgData//Prescriptions//MsaviData.shp', False, True, '13.539231,13.547340,55.391727,55.398065',  -1, 0, 3,'C://Users//Matrix//Downloads//MsaviData//AgData//Prescriptions//MsaviData_poly.shp')
```

It works (I get the output) when I run it in 2.18.0 (32bits) hence when I run it on in my 2.18.10 (64bits) it does not work? (For both test I run them in an osgeo4w installation.)

When I write "does not work", I mean it does not produce any output, if I run it in the python console it returns an output object (when I run it in 2.18.0 I got the same output message and I got the files, in 2.18.10 just the output message ). There is no error message etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the correct extent? Maybe the algorithm is just processing "nothing" with success.

Comment: @axel_ande What does it happen if you use `/` instead of `//` in your filepath? However, this is a weird behavior. What do you mean with: *it returns an output object*? I don't see any part of code where you check for an object.

Comment: Beware of https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16777 and try QGIS v 2.18.9 or osgeo4w setup.

Comment: @axel_ande - What happens if you replace `grass:v.voronoi` with `grass7:v.voronoi` instead?

Comment: @Joseph I got the error: Error: Algorithm not found

Comment: @mgri it is a part of my plugin and I normally doesn't use the python object, hence when I run `processing.runalg(code")` in the qgis terminal it returns an object like `{'output': 'C://Users//Matrix//Downloads//MsaviData//AgData//Prescriptions//MsaviData_poly.shp'}`

Comment: @axel_ande - From the menubar: `Processing > Options > Providers > GRASS GIS 7 commands`, is it activated and a path specified?

Comment: @Joseph No it isn't, I can set the Grassfolder to `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.2.1` but I dont have a clue what path to set for Mysys ?

Comment: @axel_ande - There should be two GRASS commands, one is `GRASS GIS 7 commands`; the other is `GRASS GIS commands`. GRASS GIS 7 does not need a Msys path defined.

Comment: @Joseph Allright, I had some problems with the `GRASS GIS commands` not having the Mysys path defined and removing its path I was able to activate and set the path to `GRASS GIS 7 commands`.  I could then run the `grass7:v.voronoi` command. But same result as earlier, it seems to work but does not produce any files..

Comment: @axel_ande why did you delete your self-answer? It might help others with the same problem.

Comment: @AndreJ, I thought I solved it hence the problem is still there :(. Giovanni Manghi just posted a video on the bugreport link where he installed it with no error on windows 7,( I run windows 10, I hope that isn't the issue, I dont want to reinstall my computer :(

Comment: Does the GRASS 7 GUI standalone work for you?